# convert svg to Highcharts Map

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I have an SVG and just want to convert it, So it can be used in Highmaps.

for example this SVG

```
https://www.highcharts.com/maps/maps/Germany.svg
```

`Highcharts` site recommended this guideline:

```
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/create-custom-maps-for-highmaps
```

I created SVG with inkspace software, but when trying to convert it to highcharts map data using this link:

```
https://www.highcharts.com/studies/map-from-svg.htm
```

It got error. any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it was a bug which has been already fixed but the documentation doesn't include the new URL yet.

GitHub issue channel: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6654

Please try to use the new link: https://highcharts.github.io/map-from-svg/